# Sending HTTP GET and POST from Cocoa

Tags: xcode, cocoa, cocoahttpserver

I have one example of event: "http://localhost:8800/broker/event?topic=topic1&clientID=user&_method=POST&param1=a&param2=b"

I have a button that should create that POST request as the same of access that web link on a browser. I tried following this link http://deusty.blogspot.ca/2006/11/sending-http-get-and-post-from-cocoa.html, but I couldn't. I also would like to keep "listening" and get the events using the GET method.

Anybody can help me?

Thanks.